# How is the partitioning file in hadoop created

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am looking into the TotalOrderPartioner from Hadoop, and I have not quite been able to understand how and where the partioning file gets created.

My understanding thus far is

> InputSampler.Sampler sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler(0.1,10000);
>     InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);

If i configure the job object with appropriate input and output paths and run it using a standalone program, it should create for a partitioning file on the output path.

This processing to create this partitioning file would occur on the client machine, so the samples and splits used to create this file would be streamed from the various data nodes onto the client machine and then sorted and then the partitioning file would be created.

Once this has been done, i will be able to use this partitioning file a input into the TotalOrderPartitioner for various other jobs which use a input source similar to the one used to generate this partitioning file

Can someone please confirm my understanding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you implement a mapReduce job, there's at least a Mapper, a Reducer and a class that configures and executes the job.  It's in this last class that you put the code that creates the splits file (i.e. the partition file).

The logic in this class:

- configures the job with the mapper and reducer and other properties, then
- creates the partition file and finally
- submits the job for execution

This approach makes the creation of the partition file part of the overall flow and keeps the job submission a one step action.

Comment: I agree, lets name that class the "Driver class", however i was inquiring where this code is executed,is it on the client machine ? and hence the whole sampling code along with the code to generate the partition file will also execute on the client machine ... this is my understanding ... wanted to check if it makes sense

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Yes, it's on the machine on which the job configuration class runs which is usually the client.  You are correct